# How to encrypt a CD data against copying?

Tags: flash, encryption, exe, cd, copy-protection

I have an exe file calling some sfw files that has to be played on a CD disk. I require a way to encrypt it for distribution but I can't directly encrypt the swf file as after doing that it is not able call the data files. I think either copy protection would work or some better type of encryption would.

Comment: CD-level copy protection is generally a waste of time. It inconveniences legitimate users and is not much of a problem to committed copiers. Consider an internet-based keys system instead.

Comment: Actually it is for a project of mine which requires the cd to be  encrypted itself. it is not much of a problem it it is decrypted later on but i would require it to be encrpypted for a demo